# Adding to head of linked list

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, singly-linked-list

```
Student *addToHead(Student *node, int data) {
    Student *temp;
    temp = createNode(data);
    temp->nextPtr = node;
    return temp;
}
```

This code does not insert to the head of a linked list I have no clue why.
I am not using a dummy node at the start of the linked list.

Here is my entire main function:

```
int main(void) {
    Student *test = initList();
    int searchTest = 0;

    test = addToHead(test, 3);
    test = addToHead(test, 2);
    test = addToHead(test, 1);
    test = addToTail(test, 4);
    test = addToTail(test, 5);

    printList(test);

    searchTest = searchAge(test, 4);
    printf("%d\n", searchTest);

    test = freeList(test);
}
```

Here is what is being output:

```
4
5
0
Free was successful
```

The tail is being correctly inserted but not the head.

Here is the code for tail

```
Student *addToTail(Student *node, int data) {
    Student *temp;
    temp = createNode(data);
    temp->age = data;

    if (node == NULL) {
        node = temp;
    } else {
        while (node->nextPtr != NULL) {
            node = node->nextPtr;
        }
        node->nextPtr = temp;
    }
    return node;
}
```

Comment: My guess is that you ignore what the function return.

Comment: You've not shown how you use the function.  The function does what is required; you have to make proper use of the return value, though.  Make sure you create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))
(or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).

Comment: @joycem8845 It can be a result of incorrect work of the function addToTail. Show it.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I added the tail code now.

Comment: @joycem8845 I already wrote my answer before you added the definition of the function addToTail.:)

Comment: The `temp->age=data;` line in `addToTail()` should be superfluous if `createNode()` uses the data it is passed.

Comment: Note that you could have helped yourself by calling `printList(test)` after each `addToHead()` and `addToTail()` operation.  That would have shown where the problem was rather quickly.

Comment: You should have posted to code for `initList()`, `createNode()`, `addToTail(), `PrintList()`, `searchAge()`, `freeList()`... The bug was not is the code posted initially.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is not the function `addToHead`. The problem is the function `addToTail` that you did not show.

It can look for example the following way

```
Student *addToTail(Student *node, int data){
        Student *temp = createNode(data);

        if ( node == NULL )
        {
            temp->nextPtr = node;
            node = temp;
        }
        else
        {
            Student *tail = node;
            while ( tail->nextPtr != NULL ) tail = tail->nextPtr;
            // Uncomment the line below if createNode does not set the data member nextPtr to NULL
            // temp->nextPtr = NULL
            tail->nextPtr = temp;
        }

        return node;
}
```

**Edit:** After you appended your answer with the definition of the function addToTail it is obvious that I was right saying that this function is wrong.

Within the function you are changing the head node

```
    while(node->nextPtr!=NULL){
        node=node->nextPtr;
    }
```

that you are returning from the function.

Comment: Yes my tail function was wrong. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

How do you call this function? The caller should do

```
head = addToHead(head, 3)
```

for example.

Comment: There's an argument this should be a comment.  There's also an argument that this is probably the correct answer — the OP is not properly capturing the return value as shown.

Comment: Yes that is exactly how I call this function.

Comment: @joycem8845 — if you call the function as shown, then you need to show more of the way you're using the function and how you know that the new item is not at the  head of the list.  The code in the question doesn't show us that.  It does look as if it should work.

Comment: Hello, @JonathanLeffler, this is one of my first answers in stackoverflow, therefore I can't comment.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I edited the question to provide my entire main and what is being output

Answer (score 0):

What you want is more like

```
Student *addToHead(Student **head, int data) {
    Student *tmp = NULL;
    tmp = createNode(data);
    tmp->nextPtr = *head;
    *head = tmp;
    return tmp;
}
```

And then call it with

```
addToHead(&listHead, 42);
```

Or keep your version and call it with :

```
listHead = addToHead(listHead, 42);
```

Comment: Say I could not pass head by reference

Comment: @joycem8845 anyway the edited code has a bug somewhere else, addToHead should work